# ¿Cómo obtener el estado (true,false) de las variables publicas de un formulario a otro en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

Tengo dos formularios en mi aplicación de c#, el primero se llama **frmPrincipal**, el segundo **frmObtener**.

======================**Formulario: frmObtener**================================

El el formulario **frmObtener** tengo los siguientes controles y variables:

> - Variable:

```
  public bool Obtener1 = false;  
  public bool Obtener2 = false;
```

> - Controles (botones): **btnOpcion1** y **btnOpcion2**.

Los **eventos click** de cada botón los detallo a continuación:

```
private void btnOpcion1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Obtener1=true;
   Obtener2=false;
   //Resto del código...
}
private void btnOpcion2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Obtener2=true;
   Obtener1=false;
   //Resto del código...
}
```

=====================**Formulario: frmPrincipal**===============================

En el formulario **frmPrincipal** tengo el siguiente botón:

> - Control (botón): **btnVerificar**

Esto es lo que ***deseo hacer*** en el **evento click del botón (btnVerificar)**, pero **no me funciona**:

```
    private void btnVerificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmObtener _frmOb = new frmObtener();
        if (_frmOb.Obtener1 == true || _frmOb.Obtener2 == true)
        {
            //Resto del código..
        }
        else if (_frmOb.Obtener1 == false || _frmOb.Obtener2 == false)
        {
            //Resto del código
        }
    }
```

¿Cómo puedo realizar esa funcionalidad del botón **btnVerificar** correctamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta declarar ambas variables como `static` para poder acceder a ellas desde otra instancia:

```
 public static bool Obtener1 { get; private set;};  
  public static  bool Obtener2 = { get; private set;};
```

Y luego en vez de crear una nueva instancia del form para acceder a ellas, utilizas el nombre de la clase:

```
private void btnVerificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (frmObtener.Obtener1 == true || frmObtener.Obtener2 == true)
    {
        //Resto del código..
    }
    else if (frmObtener.Obtener1 == false || frmObtener.Obtener2 == false)
    {
        //Resto del código
    }
}
```

Es bueno notar que ambas tienen que tener el getter privado para que nadie pueda modificar el estado de la variables, sino solo el formulario contendor y asi evitar modificar el valor fuera del mismo sin saber donde exactamente.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que yo hago para enlazar datos de diferentes formularios.

**FORMULARIO 1**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public static  Form1 instance=null;
            public bool Obtener1 = false;  
            public bool Obtener2 = false;

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                instance = this;

            }
```

**FORMULARIO 2:**

De esta manera accedes a los controles y variables publicas del formulario 1 (esto lo puedes hacer desde cualquier parte de la aplicación) , puedes acceder o modificar, simulas un proceso reactivo *Recuerdo que para acceder a los controles de windows form , como por ejemplo un grid este debe esta de manera publica

```
Form1.instance.Obtener1 
Form1.instance.Obtener2
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Por que no te funciona? No deberías tener errores de compilación. Recuerda que en tu código al hacer un

> new frmObtener();

Estas inicializando un objeto con las propiedades Obtener1 y Obtener2 ambos en false. Deberías guardar una referencia al formulario en el frmPrincipal de la siguiente forma:

`private frmObtener _frmOb = new frmObtener();
//Abrir el formulario en algún momento y cambiar los valores de Obtener1 u Obtener2
_frmOb.Show();`

Y luego en el método `btnVerificar_Click` de tu código remover la línea:

`frmObtener _frmOb = new frmObtener();`

Cuando llames al evento click los valores de Obtener1 y Obtener2 se mantendrán por estar usando la misma referencia.